# Can I shift memory from ROOT to HOME partition - Ubuntu Linux 16.04 (dual boot with windows 10)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, root, home-directory

I have researched on my question first, but mostly I found that people want to transfer disk space from HOME to ROOT, while my case is the opposite.

My HOME partition is pretty full right now, while I have 350 Gb on my ROOT> **I would like to shift e.g. 200Gb from ROOT to HOME.**

NOTE: I do not want to change Windows partition size, I just want to shift between the ubuntu partitions.
[image]

I've read that I can use gparted for resizing partition. However, I am not quite sure as to how to do it. 
Could you please give detailed steps on these?

Comment: You don't "shift" memory but nobody is stopping you from resizing your partitions. Do it as you see fit.

Comment: Follow  issue @karel pointed above, mon. There you will find how to do it. Remember: Do it with live-usb Ubuntu, because you will not unmount these partitions at full-boot time.